# OnPaint() and MouseMove event at same time in MFC C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, mouseevent, onpaint

I have two functions- draw1() and draw2() that draws a bitmap to DC. I need to call them one after the other. So I do it in ,

```
void CDlg::OnPaint()
{
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
     draw1();
     draw2();
    }
}
```

I also want to add a clickmouse event , i.e, when i click left button of the mouse, the cursor should disappear. So I do it in,

```
void CDlg::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
   ShowCursor(FALSE);
}
```

But the click mouse event does not occur , unless the 'for loop' in OnPaint() doesn't finish.

I want the for loop to continue , at the same time the click mouse should occur without interrupting the for loop.

How can I make changes or add to get the result?

EDIT: Why the for loop?
In draw1() & draw2() , I'm reading first frame of two YUV files respectively, converting to bitmap and then drawing it to DC. I'm toggling between 2 bitmaps after 1 sec. For eg-like a screensaver. Hence the for loop.

Comment: why is there the `for` loop?

Comment: you need multitasking

Comment: You need to put your loop inside a thread. But I'm not sure why are you drawing more than once.

Comment: Painting should never take such a long time, and why do you have a loop like that? Handle the drawing and just return, the mouse event will be handled. Otherwise you ´have to extract the "long time taking routine" in another thread.

Comment: Explain more details of what you _actually _ try to achieve.

Comment: @everyone--In draw1() & draw2() , I'm reading first frame of two YUV files respectively, converting to bitmap and then drawing it to DC. I'm toggling between 2 bitmaps after 1 sec. For eg-like a screensaver. Hence the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialized the variable.

```
for(int i=;i<10;i++)
```

initialize the variable

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)// initialize with any value
```

Answer (score -1):

Multitasking.

I started a thread in onPaint() - `AfxBeginThread(Process, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0, NULL);`

In Process()- called the for loop function.

It's working now.

Thank you.

Comment: Multithreading and GUI programming are orthogonal. While it is possible to properly serialize rendering across threads, you did nothing to do so. This is not an answer.

Comment: You don't even grasp the amount of havok this created. Good luck when things start to break in the most undebuggable ways. This is not an answer to your question. A single-threaded application, using a timer, on the other hand, is a solution. It requires that you learn about the event-based nature of a Windows application.